# How to refresh a Fragment in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using three tabs and these tabs having list view, on these tabs i am adding new list items in tabs. After Creating a list the new list item is not added when i scroll the tabs then it shows the list item

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged after the new item is added to the listView?

Comment: no i am not using

Comment: Post the code where you are adding the new item

Comment: yes, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Your_Fragment_TAG is the name you gave your fragment when you created it

This code is for support library.

Answer (score 1):

> when you add item in listview call one method (make it by own) in your adapter

```
 public void refreshWishlistAdapter() {
    itemList.clear();
    itemList.addAll(dbHelper.getallWishlistItems());
    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```