# how to refresh fragment in tabs after adding the new item in list..?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, listviewitem

Hello everyone i am doing a task in android where is  i have a activity with  three tabs

```
tab 1 
tab 2
tab 3
```

here is a listview  in every tab1,2,3.
tab1 containg the list of contacts like whatsapp tab contacts.
tab2 containg the list of recent contacts like whatsapp chats tab.
and tab3 containg list of groups  created by user .

now my problem is here is a Fab Button  with functionality for creating new group,chat and contact.

now when user click on fab button then he/she will goto the new activity which is related with his choice like:
**if he want create gruop then group activity,** 
**if he want create new chat then chat activity,** 
**if he want create new contact then contact activity,**

for eg  : user want to create a new contact in his list .

now he/she click **on the fab button** and select the create new contact.

and goto the next activity name Createacontact.class which is used for creating new contacts.

after creating new contact when use come back to the tabs activity .

### **Now i want to refresh the list in tab if new data is added in the list ..?**

im using this method to update the list when adding new item in the list

```
public void setupUiData(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        ArrayList list = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");

        if (mydbhelper.getAllListNames().size() > list.size()) {

            list.add(getNewListItem());

        }

        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, list);

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    } else {

        ArrayList<Contacts> countryList = updatelist();

        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.layout_contact_row, countryList);

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: it's not working  i try it sevral time

Comment: Just add the new entry into your arraylist e.g. list.add(new item) and after that call adapter.notifyDataSetChange(). This will help you out.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325243/how-to-refresh-a-fragment-in-android/39325309#39325309

Comment: not workig     @rahul sharma

Comment: have you added the item in correct arraylist and notifying the correct adapter instance?

Comment: yesss  i have only one instance of adapter